# Is it bad to link to drupalmodules.com?

Tags: support

Whenever I don't remember the exact name of a module, I resort to http://drupalmodules.com. I think it is a very useful site, and has helped many people to find their module. I think it is also worth "paying back" and linking to the site, since I found the answer there.

I was recently told I should rather link to drupal.org/project. Is that an official policy?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any official policy about not linking to Drupal Modules.

Drupal Modules gives a rating for the module, and this could be useful information. Plus, the list of related modules seems more accurate on Drupal Modules than on Drupal.org; for example, for the Views module, Drupal Modules gives 10 related modules, while Drupal.org gives 5 links, including one for the [Follow-up](http://drupal.org/project/followup) module, which doesn't seem so related to the Views module.

I personally prefer to link the project page on Drupal.org, and the reason is mainly that:

- It is the official site
- It reports more links related to the module, such as documentation links

I just think it's preferable to link to Drupal.org, in the same way it is preferable to link the documentation on Drupal.org API, rather than third-party sites (when the information is given on Drupal.org API).

Comment: thanks :) BTW: it has the related modules block, too. (on the [detail page of the module](http://drupalmodules.com/module/views) and i think that the links provided are almost the same. And I think for a newcomer it may useful to learn about a new resource ...